# UITableView background color

Tags: ipad, uitableview

I've seen various posts on background color for a UITableView for ios 4.2 but I just cannot seem to change the background color.

```
UIView *bgView = [[[UIView alloc] init] autorelease];
bgView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
bgView.opaque = YES;
self.myTableView.backgroundView = bgView;
```

I've placed this code in a viewDidLoad but it won't change colors. My UITableView is an IBOutlet inside a UIViewController with a UITableViewDelegate & UITableViewDataSource so I'm thinking at the viewDidLoad the UITableView is already rendered and I cannot change its background color.

EDIT * - the UITableView is grouped

Answer (score 38):

Try setting the background view of the table view to nil and also set the background colour of the table view

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.myTableView.backgroundView = nil;
    self.myTableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
}
```

Comment: Note the self.myTableView.backgroundView = nil;  It's crucial to get the background working on an iPad in iOS 5+

Answer (score 20):

Simply changee the backgroundColor property of both tableView and tableView's backgroundView.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

   id desiredColor = [UIColor clearColor];
   self.tableView.backgroundColor = desiredColor;
   self.tableView.backgroundView.backgroundColor = desiredColor;
}
```

Comment: You can do this without code in Interface Builder. Select the Tableview. Go to the Attributes Inspector. Set the Tableview Background Colour. Set the View Background Colour.

Answer (score 4):

Confirm Edward Huynh solution for all iOS < 6.0 
Use the following code in viewDidLoad if you have not declared myTableView in .h

```
self.tableView.backgroundView = nil;
self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
```

Add the following lines if you want to load a pattern as background

```
self.tableView.opaque = NO;
self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage"]];
```

Answer (score 0):

use this delegate to change the color

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
}
```

EDIT 1:

```
UIView* backgroundView = [ [ [ UIView alloc ] initWithFrame:CGRectZero ] autorelease ];
backgroundView.backgroundColor = [ UIColor yellowColor ];
cell.backgroundView = backgroundView;
for ( UIView* view in cell.contentView.subviews ) 
{
    view.backgroundColor = [ UIColor clearColor ];
}
```

Comment: this just changes the cell background color, im after the uitableview itself.

Comment: not quite, again its just updating that particular cell. so the cell will be that particular color but the background is still grey. perhaps i forgot to add an important detail and that is that the tableview is grouped (my bad). It definitely will work if it wasn't grouped

Answer (score 0):

A background view that is 0 by 0 pixels big isn't going to be visible. Try initWithFrame: to give the view an actual size.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding to this. I needed to change the tableview's uiscrollview background color for a particular effect. You can do this either globally:

```
[[UIScrollView appearance] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

Or confine it to a single controller (iOS9):

```
[[UIScrollView appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses:@[[MyViewController class]]] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```